# OptionParser: show extra information and allow for unspecified actions

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optparse

(The title should be `OptionParser: show extra help`, but the word `help` is not allowed in the title)

I have this `OptionParser`:

```
parser = OptionParser(
    usage='usage: %s [options]' % (args[0]),
    version='%s Version %s' % (args[0], version))

parser.add_option('-a', '--action', choices=['menu'] , help='Allowed actions are: menu, and any menu action', default='menu')
parser.add_option('-1', '--file1',  type='string', help='First file')
parser.add_option('-2', '--file2',  type='string', help='Second file')
parser.add_option('--debug', action='store_true', help='run in debug mode')
```

Calling with `--help` gives me:

```
Usage: /home/gonvaled/projects/bin/process_json.py [options]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -a ACTION, --action=ACTION
                        Allowed actions are: menu, and any menu action
  -1 FILE1, --file1=FILE1
                        First file
  -2 FILE2, --file2=FILE2
                        Second file
  --debug               run in debug mode
```

This is fine, but there are missing actions. The problem is that some actions are defined in a `Menu` object (my implementation), and can only be shown by doing:

```
menu.showCommands()
```

That is, those actions are not defined for `OptionParser`, but are still accessible via the command line, since any action other than `menu` will be passed transparently to the `Menu` object to be processed. Thus, the help provided by `OptionParser` is not aware of those actions.

How can I tell the `OptionParser` object that when showing the help text, some external piece of information must be added? Appending at the end would be enough. I have taken a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html), but no such option seems available.

### EDIT

Actually running my program has shown that not only the help is missing. Even worse: `optparse` complains about unknown actions:

```
gonvaled@pegasus ~ » process_json.py -a prettyfy-from-obj
Usage: /home/gonvaled/projects/bin/process_json.py [options]

process_json.py: error: option -a: invalid choice: 'prettyfy-from-obj' (choose from 'menu')
```

How can I tell `optparse` to accept unspecified values for `action`?

Answer (score 0):

The list you send to the `choices` parameter must be an exhaustive list of all possible parameters that the option can allow. If the list is `['menu']`, then the only value allowed will be `menu`. That explains the errors you were getting.

**Note**: [the `optparse` module is deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html), you should use [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)

## The simpler solution

Don't use `choices` and validate the argument afterwards.

```
parser.add_option('-a', '--action', help='Allowed actions are: menu, and any menu action', default='menu')
#...
options, args = parser.parse_args()

if options.action not in menu.showCommands():
    parser.error('Invalid action specified: %s' % options.action)
```

Alternatively, if you can't do that, if you use the action calling `menu.call(action, params)` and it raises a `UnavailableAction` exception:

```
parser.add_option('-a', '--action', help='Allowed actions are: menu, and any menu action', default='menu')
#...
options, args = parser.parse_args()
# do something as normal
try:
    menu.call(options.action, params)
except UnavailableAction:
    print "Incorrect option" # (1)
    # crash appropriately
```

If the parser object is available, you can change `(1)` for the following:

```
parser.error('Invalid action specified: %s' % options.action)
```

**NOTE**: this completely defeats the purpose of using `choices`, but can be applicable if you can not do the validation in the scope of the function/method/module that parses the CLI options.

---

**Any other solution to this issue depend on your ability to introspect the `menu` object to get the list of available actions.**

---

## Using choices

Assuming that `menu.showCommands` just provides a list of strings of the available commands, my first guess would be to do something like:

```
menu_choices = menu.showCommands().split()
menu_choices.append('menu')
parser.add_option('-a', '--action', choices=menu_choices , help='Allowed actions are: menu, and any menu action', default='menu')
```

If there is no way to get the list of actions in that format, you may have to "parse" the output of `menu.showCommands`

## Using callback

You could also implement it as a callback for the `-a` option:

```
def menu_option(option, opt_str, value, parser):
    if not value not in menu.showCommands().split():
        raise OptionValueError('Invalid action for menu')

parser.add_option('-a', '--action', action='callback', callback=menu_option, help='Allowed actions are: menu, and any menu action', default='menu')
```

This option is a little more flexible. For example, if you use a function called `has_action(menu, string)` to check if the `menu`object has a `string` action available, you could do:

```
def menu_option(option, opt_str, value, parser):
    if not has_action(menu, value):
        raise OptionValueError('Invalid action specified for menu: %s' % value)
```

## More complicated solutions

There are probably a lot more complicated solutions. Some ideas (that may or - more likely - not work) are:

- subclassing `OptionParser` and create your own that has what you need (so that choices has no effect)
- if `menu` has its own `OptionParser`, chain-load it using callbacks
- if `menu` has its own sub parser, [have argparse use it directly](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)